# Map images on Google Glass Playground

Tags: google-mirror-api, google-glass, google-playground

Does the Glass playground support map images with the glass://map url?  I am trying the following:

And I don't get an image.  If it is not supported by the playground is there a work around?  Using static maps api?  Is this planned to be supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map images are not yet supported on the Playground. Feel free to file a feature request on our [issues tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/list) to track progress.